# UISegmentedControl alpha property not working properly

Tags: objective-c, uiview, alpha, uisegmentedcontrol

Is there a fix for this behavior?

This is a UISegmentedControl full default no special properties set at all.

Setting its alpha or the alpha of the superview shows this behavior, any suggestions or is this a bug ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1L7K.png

Comment: Have the same problem, no idea how to fix :(

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem :( No idea how to fix with *UISegmentedControlStylePlain*

But with it works with *UISegmentedControlStyleBar*, and you can also set a tintColor

```
[segmentedControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
[segmentedControl setAlpha:0.5];
[segmentedControl setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]];
```